# fadeOut function not working more than one button

Tags: jquery

> Friends I defined hideMessage() function but I want to call this function when user click on any check button (I have four button). My problem is first time it's working but second time when I click on any button then it's not working. why?

```
function hideMessage()
{
    $(".msg").css({"color":"Red","font-weight":"bold"}).text("Text box should not be empty.");
    $(".msg").delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
$('#check_network_button').click(function()
{
    if( $("#network_octet1_text").val()!="" && $("#network_octet2_text").val()!="" && $("#network_octet3_text").val()!="" && $("#network_octet4_text").val()!="" )
    {
        if( $("#network_octet1_text").val()==octet[1] && $("#network_octet2_text").val()==octet[5] && $("#network_octet3_text").val()==octet[6] && $("#network_octet4_text").val()==octet[7] )
        {
            $("#network_ok_text").css({"color":"Green","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
        } else {
            $("#network_ok_text").css({"color":"Red","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
    } else
    {
        hideMessage();
    }
});
$('#check_firsthost_button').click(function()
{
    if( $("#firsthost_octet1_text").val()!="" && $("#firsthost_octet2_text").val()!="" && $("#firsthost_octet3_text").val()!="" && $("#firsthost_octet4_text").val()!="" )
    {
        if( $("#firsthost_octet1_text").val()==octet[1] && $("#firsthost_octet2_text").val()==octet[8] && $("#firsthost_octet3_text").val()==octet[9] && $("#firsthost_octet4_text").val()==octet[10] )
        {
            $("#firsthost_ok_text").css({"color":"Green","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
        } else {
            $("#firsthost_ok_text").css({"color":"Red","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
    } else
    {
        hideMessage();
    }
});
$('#check_lasthost_button').click(function()
{
    if( $("#lasthost_octet1_text").val()!="" && $("#lasthost_octet2_text").val()!="" && $("#lasthost_octet3_text").val()!="" && $("#lasthost_octet4_text").val()!="" )
    {
        if( $("#lasthost_octet1_text").val()==octet[1] && $("#lasthost_octet2_text").val()==octet[11] && $("#lasthost_octet3_text").val()==octet[12] && $("#lasthost_octet4_text").val()==octet[13] )
        {
            $("#lasthost_ok_text").css({"color":"Green","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
        } else {
            $("#lasthost_ok_text").css({"color":"Red","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
    } else
    {
        hideMessage();
    }
});
$('#check_broadcast_button').click(function()
{
    if( $("#broadcast_octet1_text").val()!="" && $("#broadcast_octet2_text").val()!="" && $("#broadcast_octet3_text").val()!="" && $("#broadcast_octet4_text").val()!="" )
    {
        if( $("#broadcast_octet1_text").val()==octet[1] && $("#broadcast_octet2_text").val()==octet[14] && $("#broadcast_octet3_text").val()==octet[15] && $("#broadcast_octet4_text").val()==octet[16] )
        {
            $("#broadcast_ok_text").css({"color":"Green","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
        } else {
            $("#broadcast_ok_text").css({"color":"Red","font-size":"18px","font-weight":"bold"}).removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        }
    } else
    {
        hideMessage();
    }
});
$('#checkall_button').click(function()
{
    $('#check_network_button').click();
    $('#check_firsthost_button').click();
    $('#check_lasthost_button').click();
    $('#check_broadcast_button').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call is hiding the `msg` element, you need to set the display value to show the element to display it again. So try

```
function hideMessage() {
  $(".msg").show().css({
    "color": "Red",
    "font-weight": "bold"
  }).text("Text box should not be empty.");
  $(".msg").stop(true).delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I have four buttons. I am calling this function on four buttons when user click on it. First time it is working when i am click on second button then message is not showing.

Comment: @user3164151 [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jraf64go/1/) - [issue](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jraf64go/2/)

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Actually i was not add there show(). Thanks